# Why the v-slot did not work in a single file?

Tags: vue.js, coding-style

I want to build a component like this :

```
<v-row>
  <v-col cols="6"> this is first box: <slot name="first" /></v-col>
  <v-col cols="6"> this is second box: <slot name="second" /></v-col>
  <template v-slot:first> something first.... </template>
  <template v-slot:second> something second.... </template>
</v-row>
```

But it return an error

```
<template v-slot> can only appear at the root level inside the receiving component
```

How can i make it work?

------Added:------

pleace tell me how to build a component like this way:

```
<v-row>
  <v-col cols="6"> this is first box: 
    <SomethingLikeSlot name="first" />
  </v-col>
  <v-col cols="6"> this is second box: 
    <SomethingLikeSlot name="second" />
  </v-col>
  <template somethingLikev-slot="first"> something first.... </template>
  <template somethingLikev-slot="second"> something second.... </template>
</v-row>
```

I just want to build a component and make the structure all above(see v-col is at the top) and put the contents following.
I dont like this way to build a component because it will make the layout(v-col) too far from each other:

```
<v-row>
  <v-col cols="6"> this is first box: 
    <template > something very long....
    1
    2
    3
    6
    ...
    </template>
  </v-col>
  <v-col cols="6"> this is second box: 
    <template > something second very long.... </template>
  </v-col>
</v-row>
```

but now the slot and v-slot seems just need to build two components to deal with this situation. Could I build just a component and achive this goal?

Answer (score 3):

You are not using slots correctly. I don't know exactly what you want to achieve but the  `<template v-slot>` should be used in the parent component that uses your custom component.

So for example if you have this component, let's call it `foo`:

```html
<v-row>
  <v-col cols="6"> this is first box: <slot name="first" /></v-col>
  <v-col cols="6"> this is second box: <slot name="second" /></v-col>
</v-row>
```

so in your parent component, lets call it `parentFoo`:

```html
<div>
  <foo>
     <template v-slot:first> something first.... </template>
     <template v-slot:second> something second.... </template>
  </foo>
</div>
```

this means that the content inside the `<template v-slot:first>` will be rendered inside

```html
<v-col cols="6"> this is first box: <slot name="first" /></v-col>
```

so the render result will be:

```html
<v-col cols="6"> this is first box: something first....</v-col>
```

you can read more about `v-slot` in [vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Named-Slots)

Comment: Thanks sir. I know the slot should be use within parent and child component,But what I really want to do is that to build a component in the style above in my question content , which putting the structure above the component and the following is the specific contents.

Comment: Can you explain your goal a little bit better? Maybe update your question and add some examples.